# Remove border of license plates with OpenCV (python)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I cropped license plates but they have some borders I want to remove the borders to segment characters, I tried to use Hough transform but It's not a promising approach. Here is the samples of license plates:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I have a naïve solution for one image. You have to tune some parameters to generalize it for the other images.

I chose the third image due to its clarity.

### 1. Threshold

In such cases the first step is to reach an optimal threshold, where all the letters/numbers of interest are converted to same pixel values. As a result I got the following:

[image]

### 2. Finding Contour and Bounding Region

Now I found the external contour present in the image to retain the letter/numbers. After finding it I found the bounding rectangle for the corresponding contour:

[image]

### 3. Cropping

Next I used the parameters returned from bounding the contour and used them to crop the image:

[image]

VOILA! There you have your region of interest!

#### *Note:*

- This approach would work if all the images are taken in a similar manner and for the same color space. The second image provided has a different color. Hence you will have to alter the threshold parameters to segment your ROI properly.
- You can also perform some morphological operations on the threshold image to obtain a better ROI.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, my problem is that by using threshold some many of the characters eliminates, I couldn't fine right parameters for thresholding so far. (I tried Otsu, Adaptive Gaussian), Is there any way to find the license plate with out binarization?

Comment: Binarization is your best bet for OCR as a preprocessing step. You can upsample your image, binarize it and follow it up with some morphological operations.